# How can I create a custom xpath query?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

This is my HTML file data:

```
<article class='course-box'>
<div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span2'>
        <div class='course-cover' style='width: 100%'>
            <img alt='' src='https://d2d6mu5qcvgbk5.cloudfront.net/courses/cover_photos/c4f5fd2efb200e71d09014970cf0b8c86e1e7013.png?1375831955'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='span10'>
        <h2 class='coursetitle'>
            <a href='https://novoed.com/hc'>Hippocrates Challenge</a>
        </h2>
        <figure class='pricetag'>
            Free
        </figure>
        <div class='timeline independent-text'>
            <div class='timeline inline-block'>
                Starting Spring 2014
            </div>

        </div>
        By Jill Helms
        <div class='university' style='margin-top:0px; font-style:normal;'>
            Stanford University
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='hovered row-fluid' onclick="location.href='https://novoed.com/hc'">
    <div class='span2'>
        <div class='course-cover'>
            <img alt='' src='https://d2d6mu5qcvgbk5.cloudfront.net/courses/cover_photos/c4f5fd2efb200e71d09014970cf0b8c86e1e7013.png?1375831955' style='width: 100%'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='span10'>
        <h2 class='coursetitle' style='margin-top: 10px'>
            <a href='https://novoed.com/hc'>
                Hippocrates Challenge
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class='description' style='width: 70%'>
            Hippocrates Challenge 2014 is a course designed for anyone with an interest in medicine. The course focuses on teaching anatomy in an interactive way, students will learn about diagnosis and treatment planning while...
        </p>
        <div style='margin-right: 10px'>
            <a class='btn action-btn novoed-primary' href='https://novoed.com/users/sign_up?class=hc'>
                Sign Up
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

from above the code i need to fetch the following tag class values.

1. coursetitle
2. coursetitle href link
3. pircetag
4. timeline inline-block
5. uinversity
6. description
7. instructor name

but coursetitle is available in two places but i need only once. same instructor name does not contain any specifi tag to fecth.

my xpath queries are:

```
    novoedData = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    courseTitle = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/h2[re:test(@class, "coursetitle")]/a/text()').extract()
    courseDetailLink = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/h2[re:test(@class, "coursetitle")]/a/@href').extract()
    courseInstructorName = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/text()').extract()
    coursePriceType = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/figure[re:test(@class, "pricetag")]/text()').extract()
    courseShortSummary = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "hovered row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/p[re:test(@class, "description")]/text()').extract()
    courseUniversity = novoedData.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "row-fluid")]/div[re:test(@class, "span10")]/div[re:test(@class, "university")]/text()').extract()
```

but the number of values in each list variable is difference:

```
len(courseTitle) = 40 (two times because of repetition)
len(courseDetailLink) = 40 (two times because of repetition)
len(courseInstructorName) = 160 (some unwanted character is coming because no specific tag for this value)
len(coursePriceType) = 20 (correct count no repetition)
len(courseShortSummary)= 20 (correct count no repetition)
len(courseUniversity) = 20 (correct count no repetition)
```

kindly modify my xpath query to solve my problem. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need that `re:test`, simply do:

```
>>> s = sel.xpath('//div[@class="row-fluid"]/div[@class="span10"]')[0]
>>> len(s)
1
>>> s.xpath('h2[@class="coursetitle"]/a/@href').extract()
[u'https://novoed.com/hc']
```

also note that once `s` is set on the right place you can just continue from it.